# Why the Process.GetProcessesByName("msiexec") shows wrong result?

Tags: c#, .net, process

At some point I need to catch the events of `msiexec` process launching and its finishing. My code is working with usual user permissions. The `msiexec` process will be started by Windows with system privileges, therefore I can't do `Refresh()` and to check the `HasExited` property of  that process.

```
while (true) {
    Process[] msi = Process
        .GetProcessesByName("msiexec");

    if (msi.Length > 0) break;
}

// The `msiexec` is launched. Now to wait its finishing...  

while (true) {
    Process[] msi = Process
        .GetProcessesByName("msiexec");

    if (msi.Length == 0) break; // Here is `false` always!
}

// Components was installed.
```

But second `while` loop always shows `msi.Length == 1` even after `msiexec` will be finished. Why does it happen? How can I solve it?

Comment: So you look in all system processes and there are *NO* msiexec processes running? You're 100% sure of this? If so, then you've just found a bug in .NET.

Comment: Instead of using a loop, can't you just call the `WaitForExit()` method after you have found the process?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, no it doesn't work. I tried it before I created this theme. The problem is that `msiexec` works with system rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware of the fact that several processes with the same name can be running at the same time. So, `msi.Length` can be > 1. It could also be > 0 before you launch msiexec.

Once you have found the msiexec process, instead of calling `GetProcessesByName` again, you could test the `HasExited` property of the process.

If `msi.Length` was > 1, then wait until the number of non exited processes drops by 1.

Comment: No, I can't. I have the exception with the message about I haven't necessary rights for getting the `HasExited` value. Windows can't install several applications at the same time. Therefore `msiexec` always will be one (in my opinion).

Comment: I already saw setups that launched child setups, resulting in more than one msiexec in the task manager. See (random image showing several msiexecs): https://williamsitblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/image3.png

Comment: Also make sure that your app runs in 64 bit. A 64 bit process can access a 32 process, but not vice-versa: Found info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx (second Note). Also you need full-trust permission (3rd Note in same link).

Comment: I compile my code as `AnyCPU`. I see in debug mode that both `msi.Length` are `1`. If I open Task Manager and require to show the process of all users, then I see `msiexec` even after finishing of the installing.

Comment: @AndreyBushman you simply miss the fact the when you run the command of msiexec to install a thing, the Windows Installer service will launch and its process is also msiexec (/V), so there can be multiple processes, as this answer said. And that service will not stop itself after your installation task finishes, which answered what you see with Task Manager. I hope you learn Process Explorer tool from Microsoft SysInternal Suite, as that's much better than Task Manager in this case showing you more about the processes.